# How to deploy ECS Service with HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I built a simple web API docker image. I pushed it to `ECR` and later deployed as a `Service` to `ECS Cluster` (`Fargate` launch type). I'm inside the VPN and using private IP to test. The problem I have is that I only works when I call `http://address/api/...` It doesn't work for `https://`.

I don't understand why, because when I was running it in docker on my machine (in Desktop Docker) it only worked via `https`. Can you explain why?

Comment: HTTP uses port 80, HTTPS uses port 443. What are your load balancer listener settings? What are your target group port configuration settings?

Comment: @MarkB In the `Load balancer type` I didn't select anything. Should I select Application Load Balancer, Network Load Balancer or Classic Load Balancer?

Comment: @MarkB Also, in the security group of my ECS Service, should I set inbound rule to allow port 443? (currently it only has HTTP port 80)

Comment: Are you hitting your ECS service directly instead of through a load balancer? If so then yes you probably just need to open port 443 in the security group.

Comment: @MarkB I'm not using load balancer. I added HTTPS to inbound rules, but it didn't work

Comment: How did you have it working locally? I assume you have an SSL certificate installed in the docker container, and your web server is configured to use it? And you have your docker container configured to expose both ports 80 and 443?

Comment: @MarkB Well, I installed Desktop Docker, didn't change anything. Then I simply run it via Visual Studio (I set it to run in Docker). And that's it. It doesn't work with http locally. Only with https

Comment: I think you need to figure out how to run it from the Docker command line, to understand what settings you need to pass to ECS and what ports you need to use, etc. Or at least look at your Visual Studio docker settings and understand what it is doing. As it is you don't have enough info about your docker container's configuration to properly make HTTPS work in ECS.